# Move a specific element into the viewport in GoJS

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, gojs

When displaying a [context menu](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/contextMenus.html) in GoJS, it can happen that said menu *exeeds the viewport*.

The following image shows this case, the upper edge of the image is the border of the `canvas` GoJS draws on.

[image: what it looks like]

When this happens, is it possible to **programmatically** move the whole diagram down so the menu is visible again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, use [`Diagram.centerRect`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#centerRect) or [`Diagram.scrollToRect`](http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#scrollToRect)

```
var node = myDiagram.findNodeForKey(someKey);
myDiagram.centerRect(node.actualBounds);
```

See an example on the [Initial Viewport intro page](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/initialView.html).